# can i make web server to be index server?

Tags: indexing, p2p

i need to build index server for p2p (games) application
can i just use web server(lighttpd) and extend it with some plug in?
is there any problem with this method?

Answer (score 0):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is a framework for creating network applications. It's written in [Python](http://www.python.org/). You could use this to write your indexing server.

Not knowing any more about what kind of server you are wanting to write makes it impossible to say anything more, but it is unlikely that you can just extend an existing web server with some plugins.

Comment: simple server that keeps the ip list of the p2p clients 
like centralized peer-to-peer architecture